# SOLVED - Rofi on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, error when try to ./configure

Tags: kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 LTS and I'm trying to build Rofi, but when I try to ./configure in the directory, this comes up. What can I do?

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gio-2.0) were not met:

No package 'gio-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables _NKUTILS_INTERNAL_GIO_CFLAGS
and _NKUTILS_INTERNAL_GIO_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I already tried to edit the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` but didn't work.

Comment: Looks like you need to install the [libglib2.0-dev package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libglib2.0-dev)

Comment: Why not install from the repositories? That avoids the need to compile.

Comment: @steeldriver yes, that was the problem